Eventlog : EventWrite not writing data to EventLog
I am trying to Write EventData(C Struct like) to Application Eventlog using "EventWrite".
I don't see any Log written to EventLog(Application)
I am using the below sprovider.mc file
MessageIdTypedef=DWORD

SeverityNames=( 
    Success=0x0:STATUS_SEVERITY_SUCCESS
    Informational=0x1:STATUS_SEVERITY_INFORMATIONAL
    Warning=0x2:STATUS_SEVERITY_WARNING
    Error=0x3:STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR
)

FacilityNames=( 
    System=0x0:FACILITY_SYSTEM
    Runtime=0x2:FACILITY_RUNTIME
)
    
MessageId=0x0002
Severity=Error
Facility=Runtime
SymbolicName=MSG_RUNTIME_ERROR
Language=English
This is a runtime error message
.

Generating resource DLL
mc -U sprovider.mc
rc sprovider.rc
link -dll -noentry -out:sprovider.dll sprovider.res /MACHINE:X64

And my Manifest file is as below
    <instrumentationManifest
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events"
    xmlns:win="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/events"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    >
    <instrumentation>
    <events>
      <provider name="evtlog" guid="{78A1B3DE-42A7-4111-85B2-8D199812EDDF}" symbol="MSG_RUNTIME_ERROR"
                 resourceFileName="c:\\windows\\system32\\evtlog.dll" 
                messageFileName="c:\\windows\\system32\\evtlog.dll">
        <events>
          <event symbol="MSG_RUNTIME_ERROR" value="2" version="0" level="win:Error" template="MyEventTemplate"/>
        </events>
        <templates>
          <template tid="MyEventTemplate">
            <data name="Message" inType="win:UnicodeString"/>
        <data name="UserName" inType="win:UnicodeString"/>
          </template>
        </templates>
      </provider>
    </events>
  </instrumentation>
</instrumentationManifest>

I run
wevtutil im evnt.man
Warning: The resource file for publisher sprovider does not contain the metadata resource.
Make sure to link the .bin file generated by the Message Compiler into the
specified binary.
resourceFileName: c:\windows\system32\sprovider.dll
I am using Win32 code as below to write events
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <evntprov.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "evtlog.h"

using namespace std;


// Define the provider GUID
static const GUID MyProviderGuid =
{ 0x78a1b3de, 0x42a7, 0x4111, {  0x85, 0xb2, 0x8d, 0x19, 0x98, 0x12, 0xed, 0xdf } };

int wmain() {
    // Register the event provider
    REGHANDLE hProvider = NULL;
    if (EventRegister(&MyProviderGuid, NULL, NULL, &hProvider) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        // Handle the error
        std::cout << GetLastError();
        return 1;
    }

    // Sample structured data
    struct MyEventData {
        WCHAR Message[MAX_PATH];
        WCHAR UserName[MAX_PATH];
    };

    MyEventData eventData = { L"Sree", L"This is a test message" };

    // Event data descriptors
    EVENT_DATA_DESCRIPTOR dataDescriptors[2];
    EventDataDescCreate(&dataDescriptors[0], eventData.Message, (ULONG)(MAX_PATH));
    EventDataDescCreate(&dataDescriptors[1], eventData.UserName, (ULONG)(MAX_PATH));

    // Define the event descriptor
    EVENT_DESCRIPTOR eventDescriptor;

    EventDescCreate(&eventDescriptor, MSG_RUNTIME_ERROR, 0, FACILITY_RUNTIME,  STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR, 0, 0, 0);

    BOOL bEnabled = EventEnabled(hProvider, &eventDescriptor);
    std::cout << std::endl << "Enabled:" << bEnabled;
    // Write the event
    if (EventWrite(hProvider, &eventDescriptor, 2, dataDescriptors) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        // Handle the error
        std::cout << GetLastError();
        return 1;

    }
    // Unregister the event provider
    EventUnregister(hProvider);

    return 0;
}

The executable generated from about C code cannot write anything to Log.
Please let me know what I am missing here.

Try the document sample about Manifest-based event tracing. Also see Writing an Instrumentation Manifest for more information.

Thanks @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, I read through them, i still could not find  the missing step to write to event log

1.Your eventDescriptor is different with the header generated by mc.exe. Include the generated header to use the provider. 2. As EventWrite says, If no trace sessions are recording this event, this function will do nothing and return ERROR_SUCCESS. and To reduce the performance impact of events that are not recorded by any trace session, you can call EventEnabled to determine whether any trace session is recording your event before preparing the data and calling EventWrite.

Hi @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, Thank you very much for your help. I tried to call EventDescCreate(&eventDescriptor, MSG_RUNTIME_ERROR, 0, FACILITY_RUNTIME, STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR, 0, 0, 0); I still see the EventEnabled returning False. I am using those constants from headerfile provided by mc file. I have updated the code my original message.

According to EventWrite,

If no trace sessions are recording this event, this function will do
nothing and return ERROR_SUCCESS.

So, I started a trace session with the Example that Creates a Session and Enables a Manifest-based or Classic Provider. Everything works fine.


Also see Implementing ETW instrumentation and https://github.com/jebidiah-anthony/Windows-Event-Forwarder/blob/master/Creating%20Custom%20Logs.md for more information.
Update:
As Defining Channels says,

Events can be written to event log channels, event tracing log files,
or both. A channel is basically a sink that collects events. If the
target audience for your events uses event consumers such as the
Windows Event Viewer, you must define new channels to collect your
events or import an existing channel that another provider defined.


Hi @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate for your time & efforts to answer my questions. After Starting the Session my EventEnabled is successful. Thanks again.
