How do I write XML to Windows Event Viewer in C?
I'm currently trying to log data to the Windows Event Viewer, and I'm trying to achieve something like this using C:


As you can see below, the General tab contains the main text of my log, and the Details tab contains more XML data. However, nothing I try online seems to be able to do that.
I've followed Microsoft documentation and wrote an .mc file.
MessageIdTypedef=DWORD

SeverityNames=(Informational=0x1:STATUS_SEVERITY_INFORMATIONAL)

FacilityNames=(System=0x0FF 
                Application=0xFFF)

LanguageNames=(English=0x409:MSG00409)

MessageId=0x111
Severity=Informational
Facility=Application
SymbolicName=MSG_CMD_EXEC
Language=English
Command executed: %1.
Path: %2.
.

And here's my current C code that's is only able to modify the General Tab.
HANDLE event_source = RegisterEventSource(NULL, "CommandLine");
if (event_source == NULL) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\u26A0\uFE0F Failed to log event: could not register the event source.\n");
    return;
}

// Write param to general event viewer tab
char* params[2];
params[0] = "cd";
params[1] = "<Data Name='path'>/usr/bin</Data>";

if (!ReportEvent(event_source, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, MSG_CMD_EXEC, NULL, 2, 0, params, NULL)) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to log event: ReportEvent() failed with status %d.\n", GetLastError());
}

DeregisterEventSource(event_source);

Is there a way to change that? Thanks!

First, you can't log XML with ReportEvent() and get the results you want. Second, there are multiple logging APIs and you are using the old pre-Vista Event Logging API. Try using the newer post-Vista Event Log or post-Win10 TraceLogging API instead.

I'll try that; thanks. Is everything <window.h> pre-vista?

No, of course not. It is still the main header for Windows development. But it does get reorganized internally from time to time, and new things added to it all the time. So you have to pay attention to the documentation.

I got TraceLogging set up. Do you know how I can make the TraceLogs appear in the EventViewer? I'm not able to right now.. I also looked at the API documentation for post-Vista Event Logs and I don't see how I'm supposed to write to the event log

Did you read the documentation I linked to in my earlier comment? Such as Providing Events and TraceLogging C/C++ Quick Start. Event Viewer is a consumer of these events, so they should show up if you register and write the events correctly. And no, I can't help you further with that, as I have no experience working with these newer APIs (I'm also a ReportEvent() user).

@Justin You also can see the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78575971/eventlog-eventwrite-not-writing-data-to-eventlog which includes some more information about implementing ETW instrumentation and where I and sreeR both make it work. The Windows Event Viewer is just an event consumer. If you want to see it in the Windows Event Viewer, you must define new channels to collect your events or import an existing channel that another provider defined.
